# Gitpitch creating custom colors

Tags: colors, gitpitch

I am starting and creating a gitpitch presentation and it works great.
I want to create a custom color so that I can use it in the presentation
but it does not work.

In the custom.css file, which I now is added correctly since other stuff in there are being displayed I add...

```css
.myblue {
    color: #65656c;
}
```

Then in PITCHME.md I add...

```md
@snap[west]
Create container<br>
@color[#65656c](singularity build)<br>
@color[myblue](Install software)<br>
@snapend
```

in this example "singularity build" gets the right color, but "install software" does not.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a custom style, such as `myblue`, you can make use of that style by referencing the *class* as follows:

```md
@snap[west]
Create container<br>
@color[#65656c](singularity build)<br>
@css[myblue](Install software)<br>
@snapend
```

Note how I used the `@css` shortcut syntax to activate the `myblue` class on the *Install software* text. You can learn about all of the available GitPitch markdown shortcuts in the docs [here](https://gitpitch.com/docs/markdown-features/shortcuts). And you find specific examples using the `@css` shortcut syntax right [here](https://gitpitch.com/docs/markdown-features/shortcuts#set-custom-css-class).

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. I guess the example I followed got it wrong